# CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession is not working on API level 30 (Android 11)

Tags: android, frame-rate, android-camera2, android-11, highspeed

I made an application using `camera2.CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession` api
to acquire 120fps camera capture and it worked very well.
(Samsung Galaxy 10 with Android version 11)

However, after the Android version 11 update,
the preview is a black screen.

As a result of finding the problem, the camera was well opened,
but `CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback` was not called.

```java
private CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession mSCameraSession;

List<CaptureRequest> mPreviewBuilderBurst = new ArrayList<CaptureRequest>();

mPreviewBuilderBurst = mSCameraSession.createHighSpeedRequestList(mPreviewBuilder.build());
mSCameraSession.setRepeatingBurst(mPreviewBuilderBurst, mSessionCaptureCallback, mCameraListenerHandler);

private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mSessionCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {

        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
    }
};
```

Is there anyone who can help me?